# Fragment Removed from View Hierarchy at Start of Animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, fragmenttransaction

I have a fragment placed between two other views that I need to transition out of view smoothly.  I have set up a fragment animation to scale the fragment out of view.  This works fine.  However, the fragment's view is immediately taken out of the view hierarchy as soon as the animation starts, causing the view below the fragment to collapse over the fragment's view.  How can I get the view below the fragment to transition up and down smoothly with the scaling of the fragment?

Here is an example of what happens:

[image]

Here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnHide = findViewById(R.id.btn_hide);
    Button btnShow = findViewById(R.id.btn_show);

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_middle);

    btnHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                ft.hide(fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "fragment is null!");
            }
        }
    });

    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fragment != null){
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                ft.show(fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "fragment is null!");
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="TextViewTop"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_middle"
    android:name="my.packagename.mytestapplication.TestFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_top"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_bottom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="TextViewBottom"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frag_middle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_hide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hide Fragment"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Fragment"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Here is an example of the animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="2000">

<scale
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:toYScale="1"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:toXScale="1" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is easier way to implement this animation with `Transition API`. `TransitionManager` can handle and animate view or view hierarchy changes. When you hide/show fragment you just change visibility of fragment view.

```
private void toggle() {
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_middle);
    ViewGroup parentViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.parentViewGroup);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parentViewGroup, new AutoTransition());
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (show) {
        ft.show(fragment);
    } else {
        ft.hide(fragment);
    }
    ft.commitNow();

    show = !show;
}
```

Important thing here is to use `commitNow` method instead of `commit`. Because `commitNow` execute fragment transaction immediately and thats why `TransitionManager`  handle view changes. With `commit` it doesnt work because `commit` executes transaction  asynchronously.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    ...
    android:id="@+id/parentViewGroup">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag_middle"
        android:name="TestFragment"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_top"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've add `width` and `height` to `fragment` in this xml.  Here is result:

[image]

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than the one I came up with so I am marking this as the accepted answer.   I played around with TransitionManager in the begining, but I couldn't get it to work right.  I now believe it was simply because  I was calling commit() instead of commitNow() so plus one for that.

Answer (score 0):

After several more hours of working on this I came up with my own solution. It's not perfect and I'm not sure if it's the right or best way to do this, but here it is.

I completely scrapped the idea of using the setCustomAnimations method of FragmentTransaction and went with animating the view of the fragment with ObjectAnimator instead.

The only code I changed from above was the two button onClick listeners.  Here is the updated onClickListener code:

```
 btnHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fragment != null  && fragment.getView() != null) {

                final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = fragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
                final int startHeight = fragment.getView().getMeasuredHeight();
                Log.d(TAG, "startHeight is " + startHeight);
                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fragment.getView(), "scaleY", 0f).setDuration(500);

                animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        float yVal = (float)animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        params.height = (int)(yVal * startHeight);
                        fragment.getView().requestLayout();
                    }
                });

                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.hide(fragment);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                    @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                });

                animator.start();

            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "fragment is null!");
            }
        }
    });

    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null){

                final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = fragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
                fragment.getView().measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                final int endHeight = fragment.getView().getMeasuredHeight();
                Log.d(TAG, "endHeight is " + endHeight);
                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fragment.getView(), "scaleY", 1f).setDuration(500);

                animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        float yVal = (float)animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        Log.d(TAG, "animation height is " + yVal);
                        params.height = (int)(yVal * endHeight);
                        Log.d(TAG, "height is " + params.height);
                        fragment.getView().requestLayout();
                    }
                });

                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.show(fragment);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
                    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
                });

                animator.start();

            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "fragment is null!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the way it looks now:

[image]

It's still not perfect, but it's closer to what I am looking for.